# Pseudo elements not working on Bootstrap Modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try this table with this style on Bootstrap Modal, and it does not work to highlight the column and row.
If i use it inside html file body it works. Can anyone help me with some hint what is problem?

Style.css

```
.custom-table-matrix-table {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.custom-table-matrix-table thead th {
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}
.custom-table-matrix-table tbody td {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
}


.custom-table-matrix-highlight {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}
.custom-table-matrix-highlight tbody td, .custom-table-matrix-highlight thead th {
    position: relative;
}
.custom-table-matrix-highlight tbody td:hover::before {
    background-color: #CCE7E7!important;
    content:'\00a0'!important;
    height: 100%!important;
    left: -5000px!important;
    position: absolute!important;
    top: 0!important;
    width: 10000px!important;
    z-index: -1!important;
}
.custom-table-matrix-highlight tbody td:hover::after {
    background-color: #CCE7E7!important;
    content:'\00a0'!important;
    height: 10000px!important;
    left: 0!important;
    position: absolute!important;
    top: -5000px!important;
    width: 100%!important;
    z-index: -1!important;
}
```

Modal code part

```
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      <table class="custom-table-matrix-highlight custom-table-matrix-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Week1</th>
            <th>Week1</th>
            <th>Week1</th>
            <th>Week1</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>25.00$</td>
        <td>25.00$</td>
        <td>25.00$</td>
        <td>25.00$</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>25.00$</td>
        <td>25.00$</td>
        <td>25.00$</td>
        <td>25.00$</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>25.00$</td>
        <td>25.00$</td>
        <td>25.00$</td>
        <td>25.00$</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>25.00$</td>
        <td>25.00$</td>
        <td>25.00$</td>
        <td>25.00$</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>25.00$</td>
        <td>25.00$</td>
        <td>25.00$</td>
        <td>25.00$</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/anduel/ggh9qox8/

Comment: Which part specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: The column highlight, on the table inside modal does not work...

Answer (score 1):

it's because you have used the styles for `:pseudo` elements only for the specific class which is of the table outside the modal.

here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ggh9qox8/1/

Comment: Also the table inside modal, has the same classes.

Comment: also you need to use `z-index:1` for `.custom-table-matrix-highlight tbody td, .custom-table-matrix-highlight thead th`

Answer (score 0):

Use the class attribute you have defined inside the table element instead of using it inside the div in the Model part.

You should use the model body inside the table element.

```
  <table class="modal-body custom-table-matrix-highlight custom-table-matrix-table">
```

Should fix it.

Comment: It works like this, but in the modal will not be only one table.
Thanks anyway